# How can I specify a class index signature that excludes known inherited index keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to make a class that inherits a class, and specifies an index signature for all new class properties that do not exist in the parent class.

Consider a situation where you would like to specify some format for a search query that can take arrays of search terms on fields, and that inherits from a general query class.

```js
class Query {
  limit = 25;
  offset?: number;
  constructor() { /* do stuff */ }
}

class FieldSearchQuery extends Query {
  [key: Exclude<string, keyof Query>]: string[]; // not valid, but captures the gist
  constructor() { super(); /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Any ideas for alternatives? Note that there is an existing base class, and that my goal is to narrow the type of the subclass such that it can use whatever *new* key values come in that don't intersect the parent keys *and* that we should be able to type-check that the values associated with those unknown keys are of a defined type (in the above example, string arrays).

I keep looking over the Advanced Types documentation and feel as though I must be missing something, because it seems like all the tools to accomplish this exist.

Edit:
I just figured out a maybe improvement, in which you can at least exclude all value types that are not present in the parent:

```js
class Query {
  limit = 25;
  offset?: number;
  constructor() { /* do stuff */ }
}

class FieldSearchQuery extends Query {
  [key: string]: Query[keyof Query]|string[]; // valid, but overly broad
  constructor() { super(); /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Comment: Are there more than 2 classes or what's the use case? Wouldn't this always exclude all of the `Query` keys because it's extending it?

Comment: This would indeed always exclude all of the Query keys in the index signature, but require them on the class itself. The situation involves multiple classes inheriting from the parent class.

Comment: To further clarify, you would expect to be able to provide whatever field names desired for a FieldSearchQuery as keys by whatever is consuming the class, and typecheck that those *new* values (ie values not in Query) are always the ones specified by the index signature. A search using the signature `{ name: "Joe" }` (which obtains a default value of `{ name: "Joe", limit: 25, constructor: fn() ...etc }`) ought to type-error because the `name` key did not resolve to a string array)

Comment: One more clarification: the problem is that the index signature of the child class intersects with the signature of the parent class. `limit = 25` is not a valid key/value for the index signature `[key: string]: string[]` on the child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure to be on the right pattern here ? Because if you specify an index signature on a class, it would not be only on the class attributes but also on all method.

```js
class B {
  [key: string]: string[]

  foo(): number { // Property 'foo' of type '() => number' is not assignable to string index type 'string[]'.
    return 1
  }
}
```

One way to achieve your solution would be to follow the [intersection types example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) in the typescript documentation.

My solution would be to declare a single field on your class, and specify its type.

```js
type QueryParams = { [key: string]: any } & {
  limit: number
  offset?: number
}

class Query<T extends QueryParams> {
  params: T
  constructor(params: Partial<T>) {
    this.params.limit = params.limit === undefined ? 25 : params.limit
  }
}

type FieldSearchQueryParams = { [key: string]: string[] } & {
  limit: number
  offset?: number
}

class FieldSearchQuery extends Query<FieldSearchQueryParams> {
  constructor(params: Partial<FieldSearchQueryParams>) {
    super(params)
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Great points, and great solution, too! Thank you. I had a feeling intersection types was going to be the way, but I still hadn't considered the relationship between index signature and class methods. I think I got too caught up in believing the narrowing I wanted could be achieved in a less verbose way.